# Angular JS controller only instantiating once after clicking rails route

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

So basically, I am trying to use angular js to make a reporting module in my application. Everything is working fine for the first time the page loads. But the moment one clicks on the page route link again the table disappears. But if I reload the page the table comes again. 
This is the first time I am using Angular js so I am confused little bit about it.
My angular code is :

```
var fileBrowserModule = angular.module('account', ['agGrid']);
fileBrowserModule.controller('accountController', function($scope) {
var columnDefs = [...];
$scope.gridOptions = {...};
};`
```

The temporary fixed that I applied is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (window.location.href.indexOf('reload')==-1) {
         window.location.replace(window.location.href+'?reload');
    }
});`
```

I know its shit and I hate it.

The html is :

```
<div ng-app="account">
<div ng-controller="accountController" style="">
    <div ag-grid="gridOptions" style="height: 100%; width:100%;" class="ag-blue">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I have two questions :

1.How the rails views are loaded ? 
    The moment I click on a link to a particular route so only the content tag is refreshed and not the entire page and other components. Is this right ?

2.The other is how what is causing this issue ? 
    Does Angular takes controll of the app immediately after the first refresh and then does not intantiate again when the route is hit or the view is refreshed ?

Comment: That is where `(function(app){})(angular.module(....))` IIFE syntax is suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you